# Return Value from one method to another

Tags: java, methods, return, frame

How do I get my inputted values from my main method to the create GUI method. I have create a frame and I have got the user to input a value in my main method. im now wanting the values that the user inputted to be displayed on the frame

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
* This program displays an empty frame.
*/
public class SimpleFrame extends JFrame
{

 /**
 * The main launcher method
 */
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 SimpleFrame frame = new SimpleFrame();



    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 240;
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 360;
    final int FRAME_X = 150;
    final int FRAME_Y = 245;



    frame.setLocation(FRAME_X, FRAME_Y);
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setTitle("New Frame Title");

    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");

    int a = scan.nextInt();


    System.out.println(a);



}

/**
 * This method sets up the graphical user interface.
 */
private void createGUI()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container window = getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    int a;

    // Nothing in the window yet!
```

Comment: read up on event listeners http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaEventHandling

Answer (score 0):

Theres various ways you could do this, but by the looks of your code, you will only need to display one value (as you do not have a loop). You could put this value into a JLabel and call a function to update the text of the JLabel.

```
public void showValue(int a){
    label.setText(Integer.toString(a));
}
```

If this is too simple, look at Event Listeners as suggested in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Example for updating label:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    label.setText(String.valueOf(scan.nextInt()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like this from the below given example 
, As soon as user Inputs the `Value` , the text Get Displayed in GUI : `label`

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    while(youWantToTakeTheInput){  //Break this on some condtion of your choice
               int a = scan.nextInt();
               System.out.println(a);

              // Now call the below method with the reference of label 

               displayInputIntoMyGUI(label,a);
   }
   public void displayInputIntoMyGUI(label,a){
       label.setText(a); // This will replace the previous text
      // If you want to Append the Text then this is the way ,
       label.setText(label.getText() + "text u want to append");

   }
```